# Thread ordering in java

Tags: java, multithreading

***Preliminary Info:*** I am writing a program that has 2 groups of threads. Group 1 threads each have a string that they take in and compute a SHA-256 hash and stick that hash into a shared object. Group 2 threads each have a username and (hashed) password associated with them. Their job is to compare their hashed passwords with the ones in the shared object to "crack" the passwords.

***Problem:*** I currently have that working, but am trying to find a way to make sure that the group 2 threads output the users in the same order of the original file. One issue is that it's a requirement for this program to print the username and password (if a match is found) as soon as the hash is computed. How can I manage to keep this requirement but still print them out in the order of the original file? The following is my code for the 2 groups of threads (group 2 is must be created before group 1)

**GROUP 1 THREADS:**

```
private static class Group1Th implements Runnable {
    private String passToHash;
    private SharedDict shared;
    private Lock lock;
    public Group1Th(String passToHash, Lock lock, SharedDict shared) {
        this.passToHash = passToHash;
        this.shared = shared;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void run() {
        MessageDigest md = null;
        try {md = MessageDigest.getInstance ("SHA-256");}
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
        String password = this.passToHash;
        byte[] data = null;
        try {data = password.getBytes ("UTF-8");} 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
            md.update(data);
            data = md.digest();
        }
        String hexData = Hex.toString(data);
        //System.out.println("Hash for (" + password + "): " + hexData);
        {synchronized(shared) {
            shared.hashed.add(hexData);
            shared.unhashed.add(password);
            shared.notifyAll();
        }}
    }
}
```

**GROUP 2 THREADS:**

```
private static class Group2Th implements Runnable {
    private String dbUser;
    private String dbHashedPass;
    private SharedDict shared = new SharedDict();
    //lprivate int current = -1;

    public Group2Th(String dbUser, String dbHashedPass, SharedDict shared) {
        this.dbUser = dbUser;
        this.dbHashedPass = dbHashedPass;
        this.shared = shared;
        //this.current = -1;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from G2 Thread: " + this.dbUser + " ==> " + this.dbHashedPass);
        {synchronized(shared) {
            boolean broken = false;
            while (broken == false) {   
                try {
                    shared.wait();
                    for (int i=0; i < shared.hashed.size(); i++) {
                        if (shared.hashed.get(i).equals(dbHashedPass)) {
                            System.out.println(dbUser + " " + shared.unhashed.get(i));
                            broken = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }}
    }
}
```

Comment: Group2 does not make much sense to do with multiple threads. Creates just higher than necessary lock contention. If you enqueue group1 in an thread pool executor, then iterate over the list of futures blocking until they are done you would have the correct order and can do the comparision from that thread.

Comment: Would that still allow the program to print the output of the match as soon as the match is calculated, or would I be waiting for the others to complete?

Comment: If you want to print them "in the same order of the original file" you must not print them as they are calculated, you must at least wait until the next you have to print is calculated. If the next 3 are already calculated, print them immediately afterwards but not before.

Comment: Odd. The requirements on this program are as follows.
__Each Group 2 thread must match against each dictionary password hash as soon as that dictionary password hash has been computed.__
and
__If a certain Group 2 thread finds a match, that thread must print the line of output for that user.__

Would this mean that I could just make the match in a group 2 thread if needed not print it unless a the previous thread finished? If so, what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: I don't know what the expected solution is and to what extend you're supposed to change the code. For example add a `shared.printed` boolean which your wait in `Group2Th` checks for every prior item and when that condition is met (and it's own hash is cracked) prints the output and sets it's flag. When in doubt ask the one that created the requirements how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure ordering by having `Group2Th` wait for `Group1Th` to finish its job and die.

Just look at the [join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) method.